# remove newline from end of string in bash - line continuations

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, newline

I know there are several different ones open and answered but mine is a little different. I am trying to do this in bash.

I have this file:

```
Line1 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line2 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line3 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line4 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \
```

The ouput I would like is:

```
Line1 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line2 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line3 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line4 asd asd asd asd asd asd
```

So that is is easier to read in as a bash loop. What command would allow me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a bit unclear how your input file looks like. Are these exact `\` or they represent something else? Also, what is the underlying logic here? `Text XXX XXX XXX <new lines> XXX XXX` until an empty line?

Comment: The bash built-in `read` supports backslash-continued lines when you don't use `-r`. It should read those lines from a file/etc. just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/\\$// and chomp' < input > output
```

- `s///` is a substitution. `\\` matches the backslash, `$` matches end-of-line.
- `chomp` removes a trailing newline, if present.

To also remove the leading whitespace, use

```
 's/^ +//; s/\\$// and chomp'
```

- `^` matches beginning-of-line.  `+` matches one or more spaces.

instead.

Answer (score 3):

The bash built-in `read` supports backslash-continued lines when you don't use `-r` (Other then when you need exactly this support you always should use `-r`).

So it should read those lines from a file/etc. just fine. (assuming they don't have *other* backslash escape sequences in them that need to be preserved.

```
$ while IFS= read line; do
    echo "[$line]"
done < <(printf 'Line1 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line2 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line3 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \

Line4 asd asd asd \
    asd asd asd \
')
[Line1 asd asd asd     asd asd asd ]
[Line2 asd asd asd     asd asd asd ]
[Line3 asd asd asd     asd asd asd ]
```

Comment: This is probably a good illustration of why it's important to use `read -r` for most other uses of read. Also, OP can get their desired output with the form `while read; do echo $REPLY; done`

Comment: @kojiro Indeed. This is exactly why `-r` is almost always what you want. Yeah, the non-whitespace-stripping behavior of using `$REPLY` is one I only learned about semi-recently and I tend to prefer the explicit `IFS=` setting to the implicit behavior of `$REPLY` for this but <shrug>.

Comment: @kojiro: While your unquoted use of `$REPLY` works perfectly with the _sample input_ given, it should be noted that it _generally_ normalizes _any_ run of whitespace in the input.
Conversely, Etan, your solution doesn't strip the leading whitespace from the `asd …` lines.

Comment: @mklement0 I was never one to argue with sample data. If OP can't be bothered to give real-world use cases, I can't be bothered to give real-world answers. >:) Unless it suits my argument, that is.

Comment: @kojiro: Fair enough; at least the comments here now mention the limitation.

Comment: @mklement0 I interpreted the point of the `$REPLY` answer as avoiding needing to set `IFS` because (as I believe you taught me) using `$REPLY` doesn't do that. If stripping whitespace is desired then leaving `IFS=` off should do that. But yes, I agree that `read` is not the correct solution here (mostly because of the other backslash escape problem.

Comment: Agreed, Etan. However, even without `IFS=` the whitespace _involved in the line continuation_ will be _preserved_, which does not result in the desired output; in _this_ case, it doesn't matter whether `IFS=` is there or not. @kojiro's command sneakily solves that problem with _unquoted use_ of `$REPLY`, but, as stated, that will normalize _all_ whitespace runs (which _happens_ not to make a difference here); in other words: even though `$REPLY` itself contains all original whitespace, _using it unquoted_ in `echo $REPLY` causes said normalization.

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't focused on the unquoted detail as I was focused on the other detail and yes, that does solve this specific case but is not a general solution.

Comment: I just noticed that a _literal_ here-document with an _unquoted_ EOF delimiter also performs line-continuation processing, like `read`, but, unlike with read, line-interior `\ ` instances are preserved, except before `$`, `\ `, and `\``, which leads to the big caveat: the document is _expanded_ with respect to variable references and command and arithmetic substitutions, just like a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- The first solution below reflects the OP's specific whitespace-handling requirements; **see the bottom for *generic* line-continuation processing**.
- The solutions here are **POSIX-compliant**, so they should work on most Unix-like platforms (verified on OSX and Linux).
- The [OP's own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053961/45375) suggests that the input has *Windows*-style line endings (`\r\n`). However, given that this wasn't stated in the question, the solutions here only match *Unix*-style ones (`\n`). To match `\r\n` line endings, replace `\n` with `'"$(printf '\r')"'\n` (sic), or, in `bash`, `'$'\r''\n` in the `sed` commands below. (With *GNU* sed you could simply use `\r\n`, but POSIX `sed` doesn't recognize `\r` as an escape sequence).

---

A **corrected version of the [OP's own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053961/45375)** that also handles lines ending in `\` that precede *empty* lines correctly.

```sh
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/ \\\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g' filename
```

- `-e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}'` is a common `sed` idiom: a loop that reads *all* input lines *at once* into the pattern space (input buffer) - *BSD* `sed` requires multiple `-e` options to make this work (or, alternatively, a multi-line script).

  - <sup>Note that the sample input precedes the *very last* newline with `\` as well, which is unusual, and would result in that `\` NOT getting removed; if you really need to handle this case, insert `G;` before `s/.../.../` above, which effectively appends another newline to the pattern space and therefore causes the last `\` to be removed too.</sup>
- The text-replacement command `s/ \\\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g` then operates on all input lines and globally (`g`) replaces runs of a single space followed by `\`  ( `\\`), followed by a newline (`\n`), followed by any number of spaces and/or tab chars. (`[[:blank:]]*`), and replaces each such run with a single space ().
  In short: `<space>\` at the end of a line causes that line to be joined with the *next* line, after removing the trailing `\` and stripping leading whitespace from the next line.

---

Note:

- The following solutions come in both `awk` and `sed` flavors.
- **Generally, the `awk` solutions are preferable**, because **they do not read the input all at once**, which can be problematic with large files. (Arguably, they are also easier to understand.)
- Note that the here-documents used as sample input below use a *quoted* EOF delimiter (`<<'EOF'`) to preserve the string unmodified; without quoting `EOF`, the *shell*'s own string-literal processing would parse the embedded line-continuations and join the lines before the commands ever see the string.

### Generic line-continuation processing *without* whitespace handling:

These solutions **simply *remove* `\<newline>` sequences**, and thus join the lines *as is*, with *no separator*; this is what `read` does by default, for instance.

However, these solutions have two advantages over `read`:

- Line-*interior* `\` instances are left alone.
- `sed` and `awk` are much faster with more than just a few input lines.

#### `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '/\\$/ { printf "%s", substr($0, 1, length($0)-1); next } 1' <<'EOF'
Line1 starts here\
 and ends here.

Line2 starts here, \
 continues here,\
  and ends here.
EOF
Line1 starts here and ends here.

Line2 starts here,  continues here,  and ends here.
```

- `/\\$/` matches a `\` at the end (`$`) of a line, signaling line continuation.
- `substr($0, 1, length($0)-1)` removes that trailing `\` from the input line, `$0`.
- By using `printf "%s"`, the (modified) current line is printed without a trailing newline, which means that whatever print command comes next will directly append to it, effectively joining the current and the next line.
- `next` finishes processing of the current line.
- `1` is a common `awk` idiom that is shorthand for `{ print }`, i.e., for simply printing the input line (with a trailing `\n`).

#### `sed` solution:

```sh
$ sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/\\\n//g' <<'EOF'
Line1 starts here\
 and ends here.

Line2 starts here, \
 continues here,\
  and ends here.
EOF 
Line1 starts here and ends here.

Line2 starts here,  continues here,  and ends here.
```

Note the two *double* spaces in the last line, because all whitespace is preserved.

#### [NOT RECOMMENDED] A pure *shell* (e.g., `bash`) solution:

The following solution is **alluringly simple**, but is **not fully robust** and is a **security risk**: it **can result in the execution of arbitrary commands**:

```sh
# Store input filename, passed as the 1st argument,
# in variable $file.
file=$1

# Construct a string that results in a valid shell command containing a
# *literal* here-document with *unquoted* EOF delimiter 0x3 - chosen so
# that it doesn't conflict with the input.
#
# When the resulting command is evaluated by `eval`, the *shell itself* 
# performs the desired line-continuation processing, BUT:
# '$'-prefixed tokens in the input, including command substitutions
# ('$(...)' and '`...`'), ARE EXPANDED, therefore:
# CAUTION: Maliciously constructed input can result in
#          execution of arbitrary commands.
eval "cat <<$(printf '\3')
$(cat "$file")"
```

---

### Generic line-continuation processing with *normalization of whitespace*:

These solutions **normalizes whitespace** as follows: any trailing whitespace before `\<newline>` is removed, as is leading whitespace from the *next* line; the resulting lines are then **joined by a *single space***.
Whitespace in **lines *not* participating in line continuation** is **preserved *as is***. <sup>The latter distinguishes these solutions from [choroba's Perl solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053863/45375)</sup>

#### `awk` solution

```sh
awk '
  contd { contd=0; sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "") } 
  /\\$/ { contd=1; sub(/[[:blank:]]*\\$/, ""); printf "%s ", $0; next } 
  1' <<'EOF'
Line1 starts here   \
      and ends here.
  I am a loner. 
Line3 starts here,   \
      continues here,    \
and ends here.
EOF
Line1 starts here and ends here.
  I am a loner.
Line3 starts here, continues here, and ends here.
```

- Variable `contd`(which defaults to 0 / false in a Boolean context) is used as a flag to indicate whether the previous line signaled line continuation with a trailing `\`.
- If the flag is set (pattern `contd`), it is reset right away (although it may get set again below if the line being continued too continues on the next line), and leading whitespace is trimmed from the current line (`sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "")`); note that not specifying a target variable as the 3rd argument implicitly targets the whole input line, `$0`.
- `/\\$/` matches a `\` at the end (`$`) of a line, signaling line continuation.

  - Therefore, the flag is set (`contd=1`),
  - trailing whitespace before the line-ending `\` is removed (`sub(/[[:blank:]]*\\$/, "")` along with that `\` itself,
  - and the result is printed with a trailing space, but *without* a newline, courtesy of `printf "%s "`.
  - `next` then proceeds to the next input line, without processing further commands for the current line.
- `1` is a common `awk` idiom that is shorthand for `{ print }`, i.e., for simply printing the input line (with a trailing `\n`); note that this print command is reached in two cases:

  - Any lines not involved in line continuation, which are printed *unmodified*.
  - Any lines that *end* a line continuation (form part of a continuation but do not themselves continue on the next line), which are printed with leading whitespace removed, due to the modification performed by the first action.

#### `sed` solution

```sh
$ sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/[[:blank:]]*\\\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g' <<'EOF'
Line1 starts here   \
      and ends here.
  I am a loner.
Line3 starts here,   \
      continues here,    \
and ends here.
EOF
Line1 starts here and ends here.
  I am a loner.
Line3 starts here, continues here, and ends here.
```

Line-ending and line-beginning whitespace is normalized to a single space for lines involved in continuation.
Note how the line without a trailing `\` is printed unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\s*\\\s*/,"")}1' file
Line1 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line2 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line3 asd asd asd asd asd asd
Line4 asd asd asd asd asd asd
```

Use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` if you don't have GNU awk.

Note though that any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach so doing the above in preparation for simplifying a bash read loop is probably a bad idea overall.

Comment: ++ for simplicity, and works well with the sample input, but there are two things worth pointing out (for the benefit of those looking for _generic_ line-continuation processing): if the input file has _no_ empty lines, it will be read into memory as a whole (since, due to `-v RS=`, any run of consecutive non-empty lines constitutes a _single_ input record); conversely, if empty lines _are_ present, they are simply _removed_ unconditionally, whether they're part of a line continuation or not.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT

This command will take away the space,backslash and tab on the next line.

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/ \\\x0D\x0A\x09/ /g' filename`

```
line1 asd asd asd \
     asd asd asd
```

to

```
line1 asd asd asd asd asd asd
```

I then can use:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' filename
```

to remove uneeded spaces between these file lines

Comment: Can you elaborate on this to make it more of an answer? How does this resolve your problem?

Comment: @gung: It uses a common `sed` idiom, `a;N;$!ba`, to read the _all lines_ into the pattern space (input buffer) at once, and then globally removes  `<space>\r\n\t` sequences with `<space>`. The result is that lines _following_ those ending in `<space>\ ` have their leading `\t` char. stripped and are then directly joined to the previous line with a single space as a separator. Note that the syntax of the command implies _GNU_ `sed` (Linux). Also, Austin, it would have been better to mention that you have _Windows_-style line endings in your input, and that the leading whitespace is a `\t`.

Comment: To improve readability, `\\\x0D\x0A\x09` can be represented as `\\\r\n\t`.

Comment: This will only _partially_ work with the sample input from the question, because the trailing  `\ ` will _not_ be removed from the lines preceding an _empty_ line.